# Displaying negative values in a DataGridView without parentheses

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, cultureinfo, datagridviewcolumn

I have a DataGridView object on my form that is linked to a dataTable populated based on a variable SQL query.  
My problem comes with the way that negative values are displayed with the .DefaultCellStyle.Format value set to "c" for currency.  For some reason, it places negative values within parenthesis, i.e. (100 000) instead of - 100 000

I use :

```
dgvprod.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c0";
dgvprod.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-SN");
```

and Its displays by exemple `(400 000)` rather than `-400 000` 
 
someone could help me to change it please ?
 
thank you in advance

Comment: What is the datatable content? Type?

Comment: @TaW   these are strings

Comment: But "C0" is a number format. You can't format string like that. You would have to convert to numbers first. But how are they stored in the sql? How did they become strings??

Comment: @TaW there are several columns but the column2 is stored  as int in the database

Comment: Then your sql is the culprit?

Comment: what do you mean? My problem comes with the way that negative values are displayed with the .DefaultCellStyle.Format value set to "c" for currency.  For some reason, it places negative values within parenthesis, i.e. ($2250.45) instead of -$2250.45

Comment: @Kevin - can you please tell what is your result in gridview without setting format and culture info. Then it might lead us to the cause which is giving this problem.

Comment: without setting format , its returns 4 datas - two string and 3 ints , by example MARC | ARN | 40000 | 400000 | 400000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the format

```
"#,0 CFA;-#,0 CFA"
```

The first section applies to 0 and positive values, the second to negative values.

Or simply

```
"#,0 CFA"
```

But the result depends on the specific culture and culture settings in Windows. 
The value must be of a numeric type. If it is a string, it cannot be formatted.

See also: [Custom numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)